# How to mount an external drive (in fuseblk) as ext4 file system?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, external-hard-drive, mysql

I bought a 3TB WD Elements external hard drive. Now I want to mount it to my Ubuntu server (which runs inside WinXP/VMware), so that I can move Mysql database to it.

It was auto-mounted under `/media/Elements`

The first problem is: I cannot change the ownership of any files under `media/Elements`. I thought the problem is the file system of `media/Elements` is **fuseblk**.

```
> sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00004cdb

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1244     9990144   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            1244        1306      492545    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            1244        1306      492544   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000590401536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 45600 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 4096 = 65802240 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00052a80

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1       45601  2930263040    7  HPFS/NTFS
```

Then I tried to reformat the external drive with **gparted**, but it ignored to operate on one with 4096 sector size.

```
sudo gparted
======================
libparted : 2.2
======================
Device /dev/sdc has a logical sector size of 4096.  Not all parts of GNU Parted support this at the moment, and the working code is HIGHLY EXPERIMENTAL.

Ignoring device /dev/sdc with logical sector size of 4096 bytes because gparted only supports a size of 512 bytes.
```

My final goal is to let Mysql runs on the data stored in this external drive, any solutions?

Comment: Just a pointer to future readers that if `mount` displays `fuseblk` it usually means that the underlying filesystem is actually `NTFS` or `exFat`. You cannot simply mount any filesystem as another filesystem but you can re-format a filesystem as another (and obviously *losing all data* on the original filesystem). For example, if the device is `/dev/sdc`, the first partition is `/dev/sdc1` and you can re-format it to `ext4` by running `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1` as root. Linux even supports using the whole block device (e.g. `/dev/sdc` vs `sdc1`) as filesystem target but that is NOT recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip repartitioning the hard drive. It is already partitioned as a single large partition that covers the entire disk, which is probably what you want. Just go ahead and create an ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sdc1`:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

Don't forget to unmount it (from `/media/Elements`) or wherever it is mounted) before you create the new filesystem!

If you still want to repartition it, try using `gdisk` (partition manager that handles the modern GUID partition table type) or `fdisk` (traditional partition manager), since apparently `gparted` doesn't want to deal with this disk.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really got the point, and solve it in the simplest way!